# How do you sum a total for each row of a column in a database to display in a label below

Tags: c#

```
private void tblPointsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Validate();
    this.tblPointsBindingSource.EndEdit();
    this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this._9thXIPointsDataSet1);

    int test = 0;
    test += Convert.ToInt32(pointsTextBox.Text);
    label1.Text = test.ToString();
}
```

heres my code now but it only shows the value for 1 row but i would like it to show for everyrow and add up for each new row added